# Pixels clipped with multiple text-shadows and negative letter-spacing in Webkit

Tags: css, webkit

I'm having a problem with multiple `text-shadow`s and negative `letter-spacing` in Webkit where the last few pixels of the shadow on the last letter are cut off.

[image: Cropped pixels in Webkit]

Well, only certain letters.

Look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tMeuB/1/) in Chrome or Safari (it works as expected in Firefox and Opera as far as I can tell.)

I know I could use `-webkit-text-stroke` in addition, but that leads to this problem:

[image: Problem with webkit-text-stroke]

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: dont know it bug or not, but it ok if you use `-webkit-text-stroke`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, sort of.

Here is another [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C4rSg/).

If you drop a `&nbsp;` in after the cropped letter, it fixes it. But that's not ideal.

I tried using a similar technique with an `:after` pseudo element, but it doesn't work.

Fortunately enough for me, the text I'm trying to apply this style to *is* a pseudo element, so it was easy to throw a `\00A0` in the `content:''`.

Comment: I have the same problem on my blog: can you help me to solve?
http://www.michelepierri.it/blog/#.UmBmfVAdfD4 thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I'd say it's a drawing bug. It appears webkit lets the box around the letter crop the shadow when you start using negative letter spacing.

I found it easier to see the problem by increasing the size and doing `display: inline` to get a collapsed box around the letter.

http://jsfiddle.net/tMeuB/3/

### Firefox

*As of version 7.0.1*

Notice how the shadow stays as the negative letter spacing increases from left to right.

[image: Firefox]

### Safari

*As of version 5.1.1 (7534.51.22)*

Same test. See how the shadow gets cropped as letter spacing increases. In frame 3 you can almost see how the algorithm calculates it. I'd guess the amount of clipping = glyph width - glyph box width.

[image]